# Dask Distributed file upload throws FileNotFound

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have four Docker containers, Flask, one Dask scheduler and two Dask workers.

I need to run code in the workers submitted from the Scheduler/Client. For that I use `upload_file` as described [here](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.upload_file).

The error I get is that file is not found. This is the  code that runs in Flask:

```
dask_client = Client('127.0.0.1:8786') 
dask_client.upload_file('predict_worker.py')
dask_client.map (myFunc, 1)
```

Error I get in the Flask container:

```
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'predict_worker.py'
```

The file `predict_worker.py` is in the same folder where the Flask code is running. How to tell Dask where to locate this file?

Comment: Have you tried giving absolute paths to the files?

Comment: Yes, absolute path worked